# I am assigning the dynamic id to the different element in HTML, but the id's are not working properly

Tags: angularjs, html

```
<table ng-show = "noTaskAdded != 1" class="table table-hover hd-bg table-bordered">
    <thead align="center">
        <tr>                                                                                                                                                                     
            <th>SI No</th>
            <th>Assigned Task</th>
            <th>Closure Date</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Edit<th>
            <td width = "20%"> 
                <input class="form-control"  ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1"  id="{{ 'datepicker' + ($index + 8 )  }}" >
            </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in viewParticipantsComments">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td width = "30%">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30"  id = "description" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-model = "x.task_description"></textarea>
         </td>
         <td width = "20%"> 
             <input class="form-control"  ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1"  id="{{ 'datepicker' + ($index + 8 )  }}" >
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 1" width = "30%">
             <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30"  id = "description" ng-disabled = true>{{x.comments}}</textarea>
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 0">NA</td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 0"> 
             <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default">Pending</button>
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 1"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default">Done</button></td>                                                                                   
         <td>
             <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-click = "deleteEditParticipants(x.id,x.task_description,x.closure_date,'delete')">Delete</button>
         </td>                                                                                  
         <td>
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-click = "deleteEditParticipants(x.id,x.task_description,x.closure_date,'update')">Update</button>
         </td>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, i am using ng-repeat to assign the dynamic id's to the different element, and i have defined the datepickers of same name of id's like datepicker8, datepicker9 etc. But they are not getting called means they are not opening on click of that elements.

Comment: Have you tried ng-attr-id="{{ 'datepicker' + ($index + 8 )  }}" .

Comment: Yes i tried that also, but i am facing same issue there also.

Comment: your HTML is completely wrong. You have open tag you never close. Your loop will create each time a tbody and you never open a tr in the tbody. you have a td instead of a th in the thead.just to mention the first things I see. Fix the HTML and see

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your HTML because this is invalid and your browser will not be able to handle it properly:

```
<table ng-show = "noTaskAdded != 1" class="table table-hover hd-bg table-bordered">
    <thead align="center">
        <tr>                                                                                                                                                                     
            <th>SI No</th>
            <th>Assigned Task</th>
            <th>Closure Date</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Edit<th>
            <th width = "20%"> 
                <input class="form-control"  ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1"  id="{{ 'datepicker' + ($index + 8 )  }}" >
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in viewParticipantsComments">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td width = "30%">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30"  id = "description" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-model = "x.task_description"></textarea>
         </td>
         <td width = "20%"> 
             <input class="form-control"  ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1"  id="{{ 'datepicker' + ($index + 8 )  }}" >
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 1" width = "30%">
             <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30"  id = "description" ng-disabled = true>{{x.comments}}</textarea>
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 0">NA</td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 0"> 
             <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default">Pending</button>
         </td>
         <td ng-show = "x.status_flag == 1"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default">Done</button></td>                                                                                   
         <td>
             <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-click = "deleteEditParticipants(x.id,x.task_description,x.closure_date,'delete')">Delete</button>
         </td>                                                                                  
         <td>
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" alt="default" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-click = "deleteEditParticipants(x.id,x.task_description,x.closure_date,'update')">Update</button>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

After you fix the HTML check if your JS is working and verify if your code is really generating unique IDs

Comment: Now, i have made the necessary changes in the HTML, and also seeing that the id's are getting generated uniquely, but still the datepicker is not getting open on click, please help me out.

Comment: Post the relevant js for datepicker. Also assuming that the rest of your js is valid!

Comment: The same datepicker is working as expected when put outside the ng-repeat. But it is failing when it comes to ng-repeat dynamic id creation.